# i get this error "Undefined index: username" while fetching data from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

whats wrong ?

```
$query = "select name from tabl ";
if($run = mysqli_query($con,$query)){

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
      echo $row['name'].'<br>';
      echo $row['username'];
  }
```

[values in the name index are shown. i'm getting this error for username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNJzq.jpg)
[here is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlNvO.jpg)

Comment: well you are only selecting the name....

Comment: You're not selecting "username" in the database query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting only name in your query. Therefore the reason why you only get the name array.  in order to get the username, Change your query to

```
select name,username from tabl
```